# Update million rows using rowids from one table to another Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Hi I have two table with million rows in each.I have oracle 11 g R1
I am sure many of us must have gone through this situation.

What is the most efficient and fast way to update from one table to another where the values are DIFFERENT.

Eg: Table  1  has 4 NUMBER columns with a high precision eg : 0.2212454215454212

Table 2 has 6 columns.
update table 2's  four columns based on common column on both the tables, only the different ones.

I have something like this

```
DECLARE
TYPE test1_t IS TABLE OF test.score%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_..;
TYPE test2_t IS TABLE OF test.id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS..; 
TYPE test3_t IS TABLE OF test.Crank%TYPE INDEX BY PLS..;

vscore test1_t;
vid test2_t;
vurank test4_t;

BEGIN
  SELECT id,score,urank
    BULK COLLECT INTO vid,vscore,vurank
    FROM test;

  FORALL i IN 1 .. vid.COUNT
    MERGE INTO final T
      USING (SELECT vid (i) AS o_id,
                    vurank (i) AS o_urank,
                    vscore (i) AS o_score FROM DUAL) S
      ON (S.o_id = T.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET T.crank = S.o_crank
      WHERE T.crank <> S.o_crank;
```

Since the numbers are with high precision is it slowing down?

I tried Bulk Collect and Merge combination still its taking time ~ 30 mins for worst case scenario if I have to update 1 million rows.

Is there something with rowid?
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you go over the execution plan?

Comment: Do the tables have indexes? If not try to index them and then run the update query which will be way faster than the normal tables

Comment: yes I have index on all 4 columns and the primary key col

Comment: It will be faster if the implementation is to run the update row-by-row, but that would still be slower than a single query.

Comment: I have something like this DECLARE
TYPE test1_t IS TABLE OF test.score%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_..;
TYPE test2_t IS TABLE OF test.id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS..;
TYPE test3_t IS TABLE OF test.Crank%TYPE INDEX BY PLS..;
vscore    test1_t;
vid     test2_t;
vurank    test4_t;
BEGIN
 SELECT id,score,urank
 BULK   COLLECT INTO vid,vscore,vurank
 FROM   test;
 FORALL i IN 1 .. vid.COUNT
  MERGE INTO final T
  USING      (SELECT vid (i) AS o_id,vurank (i) AS o_urank,vscore (i) AS o_score FROM   DUAL) S
  ON         (S.o_id = T.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET T.crank = S.o_crank WHERE  T.crank <> S.o_crank;

Comment: i will try with single update statement to see the perfromance

Comment: do not post code in comments. Edit your question please

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117988/update-multiple-columns-in-merge-statement-oracle

Comment: One million rows is not a large amount of data.  In a quick test my desktop updated a similar table in 100 seconds and generated 272MB UNDO and 691MB REDO.  Before you start looking into advanced methods, compare the obvious method on different systems, and try to find out where the difference comes from.  Even with your audit triggers, I wouldn't expect performance to be this bad.  This implies a slow server, a bad plan, or a poorly implemented trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update all the rows, then just use update:

```
update table_1
set    (col1,
        col2) = (
         select col1,
                col2
         from   table2
         where  table2.col_a = table1.col_a and
                table2.col_b = table1.col_b)
```

Bulk collect or any PL/SQL technique will always be slower than a pure SQL technique.

The numeric precision is probably not significant, and rowid is not relevant as there is no common value between the two tables.

Comment: but then I have to include commit or just let it run for 1 million rows?Coz updating this way will generate lot of undo and redo logs

Comment: Also I wanted to know will trigger degrade the performance more..I have a trigger which puts rows in Journal table for any update happening on the table

Comment: There's no way of updating without incurring redo and undo, and when you commit part way through a select you tell the RDBMS that you no longer need any read consistency blocks form undo prior to the commit point -- a "snapshot too old" error is then likely. You need to size the undo appropriately, and will incur a high amount of redo but that's the price of being able to roll forward from a backup if you suffer a media failure.

Comment: Yes, if you need to run trigger code that also inserts rows to another table, thus incurring more redo and undo work, you will obviously degrade performance. Have you considered creating a new version of the table you want to update?

Comment: actually I thought of that,but they want to track history so there is a trigger in place.If I drop and create the table everyday then the incremental changes wont be able to capture

Comment: Unless you create a new version of the table, and run a query between the new and the old tables to insert the rows into the journal more efficiently (eg. using direct path insert, or at least one single query).

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with millions of rows, parallel DML is a game changer.  Of course you need to have Enterprise Edition to use parallel, but it's really the only thing which will make much difference.

I recommend you read an article on OraFAQ by rleishman comparing [8 Bulk Update Methods](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450).  His key finding is that "the cost of disk reads so far outweighs the context switches that that they are barely noticable (sic)".  In other words, unless your data is already cached in memory there really isn't a significant difference between SQL and PL/SQL approaches.

The article does have some neat suggestions on employing parallel.  The surprising outcome is that a parallel pipelined function offers the best performance.

Comment: Appendix 1 is very important there. As soon as it becomes more efficient to hash join between the data sets the SQL method (whether MERGE or UPDATE) leaps ahead.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - that is a very pertinent.  If the number of updating rows in the source table is close to the number of rows in the target table then yes SQL approaches will out-perform PL/SQL.

Comment: If he was on 11gR2 then [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_parallel_ex.htm) might be useful here.  +1 for the interesting article, I'd be curious to see how DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE compares against the other methods.  Although I think the article is a *little* misleading.  From the table of results, parallel pipelined function is the clear winner.  But as appendix 2 shows, that's only because of a too-high DOP.  It's not useful to compare two methods in such extreme conditions.  (This DOP stuff is tricky, someone needs to write a book about it.)

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the syntax have been used and skipping the **logic** (may using a pure update + pure insert may solve the problem, merge cost, indexes, possible full scan on merge and else )
You should use **[Limit](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html)** in Bulk Collect syntax 
Using a *bulk collect with no limit*

1. Will case all records to be loaded in memory
2. With no partially committed merges, you will create a larg redolog,
   that must be apply in the end of the process.

Both will reason in low performance.

```
DECLARE
 v_fetchSize NUMBER := 1000; -- based on hardware, design and .... could be scaled
 CURSOR a_cur IS 
 SELECT id,score,urank FROM test;    
 TYPE myarray IS TABLE OF a_cur%ROWTYPE;
 cur_array myarray;

    BEGIN
      OPEN a_cur;
      LOOP
        FETCH a_cur BULK COLLECT INTO cur_array LIMIT v_fetchSize;
          FORALL i IN 1 .. cur_array.COUNT
          // DO Operation
          COMMIT;
        EXIT WHEN a_cur%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE a_cur;
    END;
```

Comment: Using a `LIMIT` can certainly help prevent running out of memory.  But I would expect it to very slightly decrease performance, because it introduces more context switching.  Breaking a process into smaller chunks usually decreases performance.  (Unless some of those chunks can then run concurrently.)

Comment: If you may set a test on the matter to compare the results, we could investigate more.

Comment: See [this Steven Feuerstein script](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html).  There are diminishing returns, but not negative returns.  I also modified the script to use larger values, but got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just to be sure: `test.id` and `final.id` must be indexed.
2. With first `select ... from test` you got too much records from `Table 1` and after that you need to compare all of them with records on `Table 2`. Try to select only what you need to update. So, there are at least 2 variants:

a) select only changed records:

```
  SELECT source_table.id, source_table.score, source_table.urank 
  BULK COLLECT INTO vid,vscore,vurank 
  FROM 
    test source_table, 
    final destination_table
  where 
    source_table.id = destination_table.id 
    and
    source_table.crank <> destination_table.crank
   ;
```

b) Add new field to source table with datetime value and fill it in trigger with current time. While synchronizing pick only records changed during last day. This field needs to be indexed.

After such a change on update phase you don't need to compare other fields, only match ID's:

```
  FORALL i IN 1 .. vid.COUNT 
  MERGE INTO FINAL T 
  USING (
    SELECT vid (i) AS o_id,
           vurank (i) AS o_urank,
           vscore (i) AS o_score FROM DUAL
  ) S 
  ON (S.o_id = T.id) 
  WHEN MATCHED 
  THEN UPDATE SET T.crank = S.o_crank
```

If you worry about size of undo/redo segments then variant `b)` is more useful, because you can get records from source `Table 1` divided to time slices and commit changes after updating every slice. E.g. from 00:00 to 01:00 , from 01:00 to 02:00 etc. 
In this variant update can be done just by SQL statement without selecting a data into collections in row with maintaining acceptable sizes of redo/undo logs.